# Full text search returns empty result

Tags: php, pdo, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, mysql-5.6

Full text search seems that not working with my query,

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo-search', $user, $pass, $options);

// Searches using the LIKE operator.
$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%keyword%' OR content LIKE '%keyword%'");

$statement->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

print_r($result);
```

Result,

```
array(
... rows of result
)
```

But with full text index

```
// FULLTEXT index.
// ALTER TABLE article ADD FULLTEXT( title, content );
$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM article WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ('keyword')");
```

I get an empty array.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

**EDIT:**

This is my table structure and its data,

```
--
-- Table structure for table `article`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(244) NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `article`
--

INSERT INTO `article` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `created_on`) VALUES
(1, 'Sample 1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. keyword massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede keyword pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.', '2015-06-18 00:00:00'),
(2, 'Sample 2', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In keyword justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.', '2015-06-18 00:00:00'),
(3, 'Sample 3', 'Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut keyword keyword venenatis faucibus.', '2015-06-18 00:00:00'),
(4, 'Sample 4 keyword', 'Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque keyword. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.', '2015-06-18 00:00:00'),
(5, 'Sample 5', 'Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. ', '2015-06-18 00:00:00'),
(6, 'Sample 6', 'Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. ', '2015-06-18 00:00:00');
```

Comment: If you execute the query directly in MySQL so you get any results?

Comment: I get this `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0000 sec)`

Comment: how come!? any ideas?

Comment: Then perhaps you don't have any data that matches what you are searching for?

Comment: run select all on your table just to make sure  its not empty ,if its not empty post the table contents ,also post the values of $keyword etc

Comment: @Dave I have the data in the table. I get the result I want with `SELECT id, title, content FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%keyword%' OR content LIKE '%keyword%'` but not with the full text.

Comment: when you say not the full text, do you mean one of the columns are not returning fully?

Comment: I mean I get no result with full text search.

Comment: Okay, then there is an issue with the query. Will see what I can come up with

Comment: thanks. I'm following this tutorial http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/PHP-How-To-Sort-MYSQL-Fulltext-Search-By-Relevancy.html#3

Comment: Have you tried the " SELECT id, title, body FROM tutorials WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('keyword') " query?

Comment: no. i dont have that database.

Comment: I added that table in manually and tested it. not working as well...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80857/discussion-between-dave-and-teelou).

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT id, title, content 
FROM article 
WHERE MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ('keyword');
```

Comment: Sort of, just a different way of asking for the same data, does it also return zero rows like before?

Comment: If I may ask why are you using " FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;" when you create the table? I have never seen this being done before, it might be the cause of no data being returned.

Comment: i don't why, what should i use then?

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the variable keyword like this :

```
   $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, title, content FROM article WHERE title LIKE '%".$keyword."%' OR content LIKE '%".$keyword."%'");
```